# How to disable button url in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, grid-layout

I tried to put # places of the url, but the url still works and `e.stopImmediatePropagation ()` with js  also didn't help. Is there any way to do this through xml or otherwise?  Thanks

```
 <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="alert_text" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">alert_text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Button</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/url</item>
            </item>
        </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in a button

```
<item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Offical dev doc
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-button.html

Ok, I got your concern. Try the below line. It adds a url but it does not work on click.

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">'#'</item>
```

Comment: Padhiyar Gaurang, thanks for the answer, but this completely disable the button, I need it to be clickable simply without a link

Comment: @RobinioTor i have updated an answer. please check.

Comment: Padhiyar Gaurang,with '#' give an error with # url  works , i solved that like this  jQuery('body').find('#button').removeAttr('onclick'); not a good option but so far only this has yielded result, thanks for you time

Comment: @RobinioTor for better result use 
jQuery('body').find('button#alert_text').removeAttr('onclick');

Answer (score 0):

When using a block I was able to set url as null and that worked for me.

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class saveData implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'targetname.targetname',
                                'actionName' => 'youractionname',
                                'params' => [
                                    false
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'form-role' => 'save',
            ],
            'url' => null,
            'sort_order' => 90,
        ];
    }


}
```